# Как получить значение строки(ячейки) datagrid WPF

Tags: c#

Есть datagrid в который поступают данные из базы данных с помощью entity framework.  Нужно по нажатию на кнопку взять значения выделенной строки и вывести это значение например: в massegebox. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Как вы пробовали? Не уж то вообще нету идей? Задача ведь весьма простая. Или вы не знаете как взять выделенный элемент, не знаете как обработать клик по кнопке, ну и не знаете как брать значение из базы?

Comment: Я с wpf почти не работал, это для курсовой

Comment: Я пробовал currentCell и SelectedItem

Comment: Я вам сейчас не про WPF говорю, хотя настоятельно советую изучить его основные возможности (привязки и XAML), я говорю вообще про работу с банальными классами, не уж то у вас с этим проблемы? Ну и так, как это для курсовой, то это ведь показатель того, чему вы научились, вы думаете просить сторонних людей решить за вас такую тривиальную задачу это хорошо, хотяб для вас?

Comment: Да хорошо, и я разобрался, решение было очень простым. Спасибо за потраченное время)